# Vuetify v-text-field label on right

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

The label of the v-input-text is on the right. I would like to put it on the left without using css, which should actually be the default. From the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/) I can see that the **left side is the default one**. I have already tried several examples of the Vuetify documentation and all of them give me the same result.

The code is copied/pasted from the docs. It seems to me that something so simple should not be an issue. I have struggled with this for awhile now. I have already tried to run several examples in different browsers: Opera, Microsoft Edge, Firefox.

Here is the code that you can find [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#icon-slots):

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="message"
            outlined
            clearable
            label="Message"
            type="text"
          >
            <template v-slot:prepend>
              <v-tooltip
                bottom
              >
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                  <v-icon v-on="on">
                    mdi-help-circle-outline
                  </v-icon>
                </template>
                I'm a tooltip
              </v-tooltip>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:append>
              <v-fade-transition leave-absolute>
                <v-progress-circular
                  v-if="loading"
                  size="24"
                  color="info"
                  indeterminate
                ></v-progress-circular>
                <img
                  v-else
                  width="24"
                  height="24"
                  src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/logos/v-alt.svg"
                  alt=""
                >
              </v-fade-transition>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:append-outer>
              <v-menu
                style="top: -12px"
                offset-y
              >
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                  <v-btn
                    v-bind="attrs"
                    v-on="on"
                  >
                    <v-icon left>
                      mdi-menu
                    </v-icon>
                    Menu
                  </v-btn>
                </template>
                <v-card>
                  <v-card-text class="pa-6">
                    <v-btn
                      large
                      flat
                      color="primary"
                      @click="clickMe"
                    >
                      <v-icon left>
                        mdi-target
                      </v-icon>Click me
                    </v-btn>
                  </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
              </v-menu>
            </template>
          </v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is an issue raised at https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1782 and at https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4552 regarding this. 
Not sure if reverse props would solve your problem.

Comment: Reverse did not work for me. The 1st issue you mentioned is just the alignement of the text, which works fine for me. It is on the right. The 2nd issue happens when using the reverse property, which I do not. I will probably finish not use Vuetify in my project, something so simple just not be an issue.

Comment: "I would like to put it on the right without using css" That feature does not seem to be supported. Why not use add a few lines of CSS if it gives you what you want?

Comment: Why can't you use the [`label` slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#label) though?

Comment: I got the explanation about my problem wrong. Please see the updated version.

Comment: @Kunukn because CSS does not work perfectly. When the label goes to the top it does not stand on the line... What I want to do should be the default behavior of Vuetify, but it is not working

Comment: @YomS. thank you for your suggestion, however the label continues on the right. Also tried other examples from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had the same issue.
> In comparing my code to the code pen example on https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=101 I noticed that they construct the vuetify object slightly differently.

I had:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

const opts = {}
export default new Vuetify(opts)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    Vue.use(Vuetify);

    login_vue = new Vue({
        el: '#login-vue',
       
        data: {
            message: "Hello World",
        },
        computed: {},
        methods: {}
    });
});
```

Their vue code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
})
```

This led me to think that their code was expecting a variable named 'vuetify'.
After checking the installation guide again.  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#webpack-install. I saw that they have two ways to load vuetify depending on if you are loading from a loader or from javascript.  I was using the Loader example in javascript.

Once I changed my code to create the variable they were expecting everything worked as expected.

Final Code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

const opts = {}
export default new Vuetify(opts)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    Vue.use(Vuetify);
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    login_vue = new Vue({
        el: '#login-vue',
        data: {
            message: "Hello World",
        },
        computed: {},
        methods: {}
    });

});
```

Seems odd that I would need Vue.use(Vuetify); and vuetify: new Vuetify()
This solution is working, but maybe someome with more VUE experience can give a better configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vue2. The issues seems to be lying in the fact that my application has been made outside the **v-app** DOM. In order for everything to function correctly, it should be a descendant of . Hence, the issue. Once I put everything inside v-app, things started working like they should. However, refactoring the code could be days of work, depending upon size and complexity.

### **CSS Workaround**

I have found a CSS workaround to solve the issue. I added the following styles to my App.vue  and it seemed to fix the issue:

```
.v-input .v-label--active{
  transform: translateX(-12%) translateX(-7.5px) translateY(-28px) scale(0.75) !important;

}

.v-input--dense .v-label--active{
  transform: translateX(-12%) translateX(-7.5px) translateY(-21px) scale(0.75) !important;

}
```

---

### **My Problem**

For me, the active labels were shifted slightly to the right and slightly to the bottom:
[image: Image demonstrating my problem]

**Suggestion**

Since your issue is more extreme, try making the values in translateX more negative.

### **Caution**

Remember - keep the ratio of the translateX values constant while doing so **(12:7.5)**. This will ensure that there is no disparity due to the length of the labels.

Comment: The question says they don't want to use any CSS to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I'll leave the answer here, as I could not find it anywhere else on the internet.